# Paho Python client version 1.6.1 and MQTTv5 ResponseTopic

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am using the mosquitto broker with the mqtt vcpkg C++ client.
I can use the v5 properties to publish messages with a reply topic.
When I tried with the Paho Python client, I had no reply topic in the message received on the C++ side.
I followed some guidelines [here](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/python-mqtt-client-changes/) for the python side:

```
from paho.mqtt.properties import Properties
from paho.mqtt.packettypes import PacketTypes
from paho.mqtt.client import Client

properties=Properties(PacketTypes.PUBLISH)
properties.ResponseTopic="myreplies"
client = Client(client_id = "client_1",protocol=5)
client.connect("localhost",properties=properties)
publisher.publish(topic = "acquisition/FifoServerParams", payload = "message")
```

but when the C++ client receives the message in the handler

```
client->set_v5_publish_handler(
            [&](mqtt::optional<async_client_t::packet_id_t>, mqtt::publish_options, mqtt::buffer topicName, mqtt::buffer contents, mqtt::v5::properties props)
```

gots an empty `props` value.

Comment: The response would be a property set on the publish, not the connect since it's message not a client thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to pass the properties to the `publish` function not `connect`

```py
from paho.mqtt.properties import Properties
from paho.mqtt.packettypes import PacketTypes
from paho.mqtt.client import Client

properties=Properties(PacketTypes.PUBLISH)
properties.ResponseTopic="myreplies"
client = Client(client_id = "client_1",protocol=5)
client.connect("localhost")
publisher.publish(topic = "acquisition/FifoServerParams", payload = "message", properties = properties)
```

Comment: Great, it works! And shame on me... in the last line a copied the wrong client. It should be `client.publish(topic = "acquisition/FifoServerParams", payload = "message", properties = properties)`

Comment: If it works please accept the answer so that other people will see that it worked.